# Methods and Timer in C#

Tags: c#, methods, timer

When I debug this small program step by step with F10 button, the program is rational until it reaches the level `timer.Elapsed +=`. after this it is supposed to go call my method `Check(MyConn)` but it doesn't! it goes back to `MyConn.Close();` and it bounces between these two, then it closes the program as of a sudden!

I was wondering where does the issue comes from ... could it be from this line: `timer.Elapsed += (timerSender, timerEvent) => timer_Elapsed(timerSender, timerEvent, MyConn);`? This was a solution posted on this forum in case I wanted to give in argument `MyConn` to `timer_Elapsed` ...

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // create connection
    string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\mike\\Documents\\Database1.mdb;";

    OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
    MyConn.Open();

    initTimer(MyConn);

    MyConn.Close();
}

static void initTimer(OleDbConnection MyConn)
{
    //set up a timer
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 2000; // check every 2s (2000ms) if the values in the database changed
    timer.Enabled = true; //enable the timer, so when the timer elapses after 2s, it performs some calculations

    timer.Elapsed += (timerSender, timerEvent) => timer_Elapsed(timerSender, timerEvent, MyConn);
}

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, OleDbConnection MyConn)
{
    Check(MyConn); // Check is a method I have in my program which takes as argument "MyConn"
}
```

Comment: Couple of things - what is the exception? and what does `Check` do with the `MyConn` object? Because you immediately close the connection *before* the timer has a chance to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you set the timer, your code will just continue running. It will leave the `initTimer` method and then close the connection. After that, your `Main` function will exit causing your application to close. Also your timer will terminate then.

In case your program is not being terminated, the timer will be counting down from 2000. When it reaches zero, it will fire the event. This happens on another thread and happens parallel to your main theat. Your even will check the connection, which will obiously be closed.

If you want the main threat to wait till the event is fired, why use the timer at all? Why not do this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // create connection
    string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\mike\\Documents\\Database1.mdb;";

    using(OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        MyConn.Open();
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000); 
            Check(MyConn);  
        }
        while(someValueToIndicateTheApplicationCanTerminate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know the event was on another thread, now it makes sense because they run in the same time. What I want is every laps of time (in my example 2sec), to execute my method "Check(MyConn)". With the way you wrote it, you put "Thread.Sleep(3000)" does it mean you let the main thread to sleep for 3sec?? if so, I can't see how the method "Check(MyConn)" with be run because you closed the connection just before, no?

Comment: Yes. `Thread.Sleep(3000)` means wait the for 3 seconds. I did not know what your `Check` was checking for. Did it check for an open or closed connection? Or perhapse somethine else? Of course you can move my delay-code before your code which closes the connection.

Comment: Actually, the Check method does not check for connection is closed or not. It just check if the values in my database have changed, and I want to be very near to real time check so I set it every 2 sec.

Comment: But even if I do:                                         initTimer(MyConn);                                  Thread.Sleep(3000);
MyConn.Close();       -- it means it will go to the Check method then put on hold the main thread for 3sec. But since the Check method is fired every 2 sec, won't this affect my main thread ?

Comment: It CAN affect your main thread. What are your trying to do to the main thread? If you "just check" something, nothing will happen to the main treat.

Comment: Lets put it another way: You told us what in your code did not work. But what you did not tell us is what you want. So: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want the main thread NOT to close the conection as long as the timer event fires the method Check

Comment: @Mike: In that case you have created an endless loop, because it feel keep firing every 2 seconds, until it is disabled.

Comment: Exactly! the endless loop is the problem in my case ... do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: First tell me want you want on a functional level (so not technical).

Comment: I want to do kind of an automatic check, I want my method Check to run infinitely every 2 sec ... I am assuming this means that the main can't close, no? I want the main thread not to close the conection as long as the timer event fires the method Check. This method Check goes to my database and checks if the values in th database have been updated and if it is the case, some calculations are done afterwards ... this is what I am trying to do!

Comment: And when does the checking end? Never? Even if some caclulations are done?

Comment: thanks a lot, but the way you write it means that the main thread sleeps for 2.5sec and you fire the method Check. Actually, I think there is a misunderstanding: I want to fire the method Check every 2 sec but the way you code it means that the checking method itself will take 2sec, which is not true ...

Comment: @Mike: My mistake. I corrected it to 2000. The 2500 was from the prev. solution WITH a timer.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly normal behaviour.

The `timer.Elapsed +=` code is only registering an event. After 2 seconds the event will be fired, but your main thread will continue as normal and return back to the `Main()` function. It will then call `MyConn.Close()` and then end the `Main()` function.

If this is a console application then it will be the end of the program, which means there is no time for the `timer_Elapsed` event to run.

If it is an application that will "stay alive", like a service or a forms application, then by the time the `timer_Elapsed` event does fire, the connection will have already been closed anyway.

---

I would suggest if you do have a "stay alive" app, then you should move the Open/Close connection code to the function that actually makes use of them. Which in this case would be inside the `timer_Elapsed` event.

If you don't have a "stay alive" app then you probably should avoid timers (and anything with separate threads) altogether.

By the way, I keep saying "stay alive" I hope you know what I mean by that. I don't know a more technical term to describe it.

Comment: Actually I have a console application. Thanks, now I understand the thread behaviour. But how can I fix that if for example I want my method "Check(MyConn);" to run every laps of time (2sec in my example) while putting on hold the thread of the main ??

Comment: @Mike: You could use a while loop in your `Main` function that sleeps for a second each loop. To avoid it being infinite you will want a check each loop to see if it should exit or not. How you set this flag though depends on what you are doing overall

Comment: I want to do kind of an automatic check, I want my method Check to run infinitely every 2 sec ... I am assuming this means that the main can't close, no? I want the main thread not to close the conection as long as the timer event fires the method Check ... this is what I am trying to do!